# How to target the value of a heading tag?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to target the value of h2 tag, like how you would do with an input.

```
const [text, setText] = useState("")

<input type="text" onChange={(e) => setText(e.target.value)} />
```

I tried `<h2 onChange={(e) => setCheck(e.currentTarget.textContent)}>Text to target</h2>` with no succes.

Which other ways are there to do this?

Comment: By `value`, you mean the text contained within it? A heading doesn't have an actual value (And shouldn't be emitting change events)

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish?  Headings don't have values, are you trying to get its `innerHTML` or something similar?  You can use a `ref`.

Comment: @DBS Yes, sorry for my wording.

Comment: @zero298 Yes, exactly that.

Comment: @D.Nguyen What to use if you want to target the text content inside of it and put it in a useState?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're asking for doesn't really make sense to me since anything in the `<h2/>` is going to be controlled by you in the component definition, but you can get a reference to the element through `ref` and then get its `innerHTML` through that.

```js
const App = () => {
  return (
    <h2 ref={(el => console.log(el.innerHTML))}>This is text</h2>
  )
};

ReactDOM.render(
  <App/>,
  document.getElementById("app")
);
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>

<div id="app"></div>
```

Comment: My wording was bad but yes, this is what I was looking for. Thanks